# JS code executes on computer but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a basic js block that works on desktop/laptop but not on tablet or phone. The code simply populates a select box based on what a user enters in a text box.  I have tested this in chrome and adblock browsers on mobile, both have js enabled and are up to date. What do I need to do to make this work on the mobile devices?  The phpPro is a js recordset populated when the page loads based on a page criteria.

```
//PHP
$pro=$conn->query("Select idpro, producer, name, vintage, barcodecase, barcodebottle From products Where active='Y' And idclient=" . $client . " Order By producer, name, vintage")->fetchAll();
$jpro=json_encode($pro);
//End PHP

const phpPro=<?php echo $jpro; ?>;

function getpro() {
    var select = document.getElementById("spro");
    var length = select.options.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {select.remove(0);}

   var option = document.createElement('option');
   option.text = 'Please Select';
   option.value = '';
   select.add(option);

   var cnt=1;
   for (i=0; i<phpPro.length; i++) {
    var x = phpPro[i][1] + phpPro[i][2] + phpPro[i][3] + phpPro[i][4] + phpPro[i][5];
    x = x.toUpperCase();
    z = document.getElementById('isrch').value;
    z = z.toUpperCase();

    if (x.includes(z)===true) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');

        option.text = cnt + ". " + phpPro[i][1] + ": " + phpPro[i][2]  + " - " + phpPro[i][3];
        option.value = phpPro[i][0];
        select.add(option); 
        cnt++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see how do you get phpPro, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: I have updated the code in the post. The top 2 lines are PHP and get the data from the db and json encode.  The next line is js and creates phpPro.

Comment: can you edit your question to add a JSON example, please?

Comment: After I create $pro (php recordset) I use the json encode so that I can create the phpPro (js recordset with the $jpro). That is the only json I use.

Comment: For anyone else that has this problem.  I changed the calling event from onkeypress to onkeydown and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the calling event from onkeypress to onkeydown and the problem was resolved.